# Fetching RecentApps - Android

Tags: android

I have a code which toast the names of the Recent Tasks the user just accessed

```
final   ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
          final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

              for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
              {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
```

But when i run my app it does no respond.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you executing this code? it looks reasonable. if you set a breakpoint in there, do you get to the breakpoint?

Comment: @DavidM : it was because i didnt added the permission GET_TASK ..

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add the permisson to access the tasks

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

;)